# choose first in window to drop the rest

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to drop duplicate rows within a window. My idea to make it a little easier was to add a new column which then has true/false values after which I can later filter and only keep the rows with false values.

In detail: I want to group by "name" and "Num". For each group I want then keep the first row if all bools are the same. If they differ, then I want to keep the first row within that group with bool True (and only the first if there are more)

```
+-----+----+----+--------+
|bool |name| Num|drop    |
+-----+----+----+--------+
|False|   a| 100|   False|
|False|   a| 100|    true|
|False|   a| 100|    true|
|False|   b| 200|    true|
| True|   b| 200|   false|
|False|   b| 200|    true|
+-----+----+----+--------+
```

I already created a new column "no_difference" in which you can see if all bools are the same or not.

```
df= df.withColumn('no_difference',
    F.size(F.collect_set('bool').over(my_window)) == 1)

+-----+----+----+--------+-------------+
|bool |name| Num|drop    |no_difference|
+-----+----+----+--------+-------------+
|False|   a| 100|   False|True         |
|False|   a| 100|    true|True         |
|False|   a| 100|    true|True         |
|False|   b| 200|    true|False        |
| True|   b| 200|   false|False        |
|False|   b| 200|    true|False        |
+-----+----+----+--------+-------------+
```

So I need a way to set the first value (within a window) to False if no_difference == True, and set the first True Value to False in "drop" if no_difference == False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using window functions, you can do a group by and conditional aggregation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.groupBy('name', 'Num').agg(
    F.when(
        F.countDistinct('bool') == 1, 
        F.first(F.struct(*df.columns))
    ).otherwise(
        F.first(
            F.when(
                F.col('bool') == 'true', 
                F.struct(*df.columns)
            ), ignorenulls=True
        )
    ).alias('col')
).select('col.*')

result.show()
+-----+----+---+
| bool|name|Num|
+-----+----+---+
| true|   b|200|
|false|   a|100|
+-----+----+---+
```